# issue with <libgen.h> and using basename

Tags: c++11

Unable to get basename to work in C++, I am trying to just get the code to compile.

This is for a school assignment and I have tried to see if it is my stdlib having issues -- however, it seems that the problem is that

'''c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<libgen.h>
int main(){
  const char *ch = "asdfasdf/asdf.cpp";
  std::cout<<basename(ch) << std::endl;
  std::cout<<dirname(strdup(ch)) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I was supposed to print out the output of ch, however, instead I get the error message:

test.cpp:8:14: error: no matching function for call to 'basename'
  std::cout<enter code here
/usr/include/libgen.h:40:7: note: candidate function not viable: 1st argument ('const char *') would lose const qualifier
char    *basename(char *);
         ^
1 error generated.

Answer (score 0):

`basename's` argument is `char*`, so this function may modify passed data. You cannot pass `const char*` - pointer to only-read data into `basename` because it would let `basename` modify const data - not allowed.

Create your input as modifiable array:

```
char ch[] = "asdfasdf/asdf.cpp";
```